# Create an admin user programmatically in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, programmatically, admin-user

It is simple to add new admin user in Magento 1.9

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
    ->setData(array(
        'username'  => 'admin',
        'firstname' => 'admin',
        'lastname'  => 'admin',
        'email'     => 'me@hackme.com',
        'password'  => 'hacker@123',
        'is_active' => 1
    ))
    ->save();

$user->setRoleIds(array(1))
    ->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
    ->saveRelations();

echo "User has been created successfully!";

?>
```

But how can I add admin user in Magento 2.0?

Comment: You have tagged this with magento-2.1 but mention Magento 2.0 in the text. Which one is it? There is a generic [tag:magento2] tag that you may wish to use.

Answer (score 9):

You can create user using userFactory

```
/**
 * User model factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory
 */    
protected $_userFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
) {
    $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
}

public function execute(){

    $adminInfo = [
        'username'  => 'killer',
        'firstname' => 'admin',
        'lastname'    => 'admin',
        'email'     => 'me@helloworld.com',
        'password'  =>'hello@123',       
        'interface_locale' => 'en_US',
        'is_active' => 1
    ];

    $userModel = $this->_userFactory->create();
    $userModel->setData($adminInfo);
    $userModel->setRoleId(1);
    try{
       $userModel->save(); 
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

You can also refer how magento creates user [git source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Save.php)

Comment: The git url shared is 404

Comment: Modified the url

Answer (score 8):

You can create the admin user by running the following command via SSH on the root directory level.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="A" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-password="admin@5252"
```

Comment: By this way, how can you set the role?

Comment: Not sure have to check out

Comment: perfect made my day!!! +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a file in root directory. for ex. admin.php

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$UserFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\User\Model\UserFactory');

    try{
        $adminInfo = [
        'username'  => 'magento',
        'firstname' => 'magento',
        'lastname'    => 'magento',
        'email'     => 'magento@helloworld.com',
        'password'  =>'magento@123',       
        'interface_locale' => 'en_US',
        'is_active' => 1
    ];

    $userModel = $UserFactory->create();
    $userModel->setData($adminInfo);
    $userModel->setRoleId(1);
    $userModel->save(); 

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
         exit;
    }
    echo "User is sucessfully created!"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one time use or if you need it during development, then alternatively you may execute the below mysql commands on phpMyAdmin or mysql command line to create an admin user.

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_role` WRITE , `admin_user` WRITE;
SET @SALT = "rp";
SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT( @SALT , "password") ), CONCAT(":", @SALT ));
SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;
INSERT INTO `admin_user` (firstname,lastname,email,username,password,created,lognum,reload_acl_flag,is_active,extra,rp_token_created_at) 
VALUES ('Firstname','Lastname','firstname.lastname@nikinpages.com','adminuser',@PASS,NOW(),0,0,1,@EXTRA,NOW());
INSERT INTO `admin_role` (parent_id,tree_level,sort_order,role_type,user_id,role_name) 
VALUES (1,2,0,'U',(SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = 'adminuser'),'Firstname');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Find explanation and more details [here](http://nikinpages.com/create-magento-admin-user-using-mysql/)

Hope this helps people who are looking for similar issue/solution.

Comment: This isn't working for me. On a fresh Magento 2.4 install there is no 'admin_role' table.