# How to create magento 2 admin user from the root folder?

Tags: magento-2.1.8, admin-user

I want to create admin user from the root directory as it can be done in magento-1.9 ,

Is it possible? How can I create a new admin user without **CLI** (SSH) and database?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175962/create-an-admin-user-programmatically-in-magento-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create user using userFactory

```
/**
 * User model factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory
 */    
protected $_userFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
) {
    $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
}

public function execute(){

    $adminInfo = [
        'username'  => 'killer',
        'firstname' => 'admin',
        'lastname'    => 'admin',
        'email'     => 'me@helloworld.com',
        'password'  =>'hello@123',       
        'interface_locale' => 'en_US',
        'is_active' => 1
    ];

    $userModel = $this->_userFactory->create();
    $userModel->setData($adminInfo);
    $userModel->setRoleId(1);
    try{
       $userModel->save(); 
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

You can also refer how magento creates user [git source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Save.php)

Comment: When addthis script & run in front then we get error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) '  in magento 2.